# add filter to admin column with a custom field value (ACF field)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to add a filter option in my custom post type with a custom field value which i am getting from ACF(advanced custom field), i tried a lot but unable to add filter in my admin columns here are some snippet i had tried but not succeed:

in my functions.php

```
add_filter('manage_edit-managemeetings_columns', 'extra_managemeetings_columns');
function extra_managemeetings_columns($columns){
    $columns['meeting_year']  = "Meeting Year";
    // echo $columns['date'];
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_managemeetings_posts_custom_column', 'managemeetings_column', 10, 2);
function managemeetings_column( $column, $post_id ) {
  // Image column
  if ( 'meeting_year' === $column ) {
        $meeting_data = get_field('meeting_date', $post_id);
        echo date('Y',strtotime($meeting_data));
  }
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-managemeetings_sortable_columns', 'hcwdb_managemeetings_sortable_columns');
function hcwdb_managemeetings_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
  $columns['meeting_year'] = 'meeting_date';
  return $columns;
}



function filter_managemeetings( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;
    // Get the post type
    //modify the query only if it admin and main query.
    if( !(is_admin() AND $query->is_main_query()) ){
    return $query;
    }
    
    //we want to modify the query for the targeted custom post and filter option
    if( !('managemeetings' === $query->query['post_type'] AND isset($_REQUEST['meeting_date']) ) ){
    return $query;
    }
    
    $post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : "";
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $post_type == 'managemeetings' && isset( $_GET['meeting_date'] ) && $_GET['meeting_date'] !='all' ) {
    $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'meeting_date';
    $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['meeting_date'];
    $query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = 'LIKE';
    var_dump($query);
    // error_log(var_export($query, true));
    }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts',  'filter_managemeetings') ;
```

my custom post type name is: managemeetings
my custom field key name is: meeting_date (which is set in ACF plugin)

if any one let me any idea any technique to filter my custom posts behalf of the my custom field value. or as in attachment if possible(if we click on meeting category it will filter the data related to that category as i want to apply on meeting year column)

[image]

kindly help me on this.